# Displaying rows from different tables to one ListView in Android - without SQL JOIN

Tags: android, database, android-listview, android-cursor

I'm super-novice at Android programming and have this project I'm stuck on.

I have a database of (conlang) dictionaries where each language is in its own table.  The user searches these and the results will display in a ListView.  Right now, I've got it working to search only one table.

I want it to be able to search all three tables and display the results in *one* ListView with rows from each of the tables.  I'd like to indicate which table each row came from.  The results would display something like:

> From language
>
> **Lang Term** : *English term*
>
> Additional information

I've set up a CursorAdapter and have this currently working for *one* of the three tables.

...

Since the dictionaries came from different sources, they have different information.  As an example:

One has the columns `EngTerm`, `VLangTerm`, `FullDefinition`

Another has `EngTerm`, `RLangTerm`, `PartOfSpeech`

And the other has `EngTerm`, `GLangTerm`, `PartOfSpeech,` and `PronounciationGuide` (possibly).

For example, table1 might contain results for "land," "landing gear" and "landscape" and table2 might contain "land," "landing" and "island" and table3 might contain "bland" and "homeland."

The user can search these tables right now **only** by the english term, and can select to match by full word or partial word.

Because of how they are structured, I'm guessing there is no way to do a JOIN query.

I don't know if this helps at all, but right now, I've got this method in my SQLiteOpenHelper class:

```
public Cursor searchDictionaryByEnglish
            (boolean matchFullWordOnly, String searchTerm) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_VULCAN +
            " WHERE " + COLUMN_ALL_ENG_TERM + " MATCH ?";
    if (!matchFullWordOnly)
        searchTerm = "*" + searchTerm + "*";
    return mDataBase.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{searchTerm});
}
```

(It is an FTS3 table it's searching, thus the MATCH rather than LIKE.)

I hope I've made it clear what I'm trying to accomplish, but I'm not sure where to start.  I've found some answers about MergeCursor but I don't know how to apply that because of the different number and names of columns.

Comment: Why don't you try with a union?

Comment: How would I use a union?  I think it may not apply, though, because "To use UNION, each SELECT must have the same number of columns selected, the same number of column expressions, the same data type, and have them in the same order, but they do not have to be the same length."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do a union if you don't have one of the columns in one of the tables, it will work if you're only searching through the common column, that all the tables have.

```
SELECT  field1 ,
        field2 ,
        field3
FROM    ( SELECT    field1 ,
                    field2 ,
                    field3
          FROM      table1
          UNION
          SELECT    field1 ,
                    field2 ,
                    field3
          FROM      table2
          UNION
          SELECT    field1 ,
                    field2 ,
                    NULL AS field3
          FROM      table3
    ) tbl
WHERE tbl.field1 LIKE '%search_string%'
```

Note the `NULL AS field3` in the last `UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Adapter that does accept the fields you require to display.